# rspec error (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am running the rspec command

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests
```

resulting in the error:

```
ms$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/ms/Dropbox/Ruby/Code/<appname>/spec/requests/spec/requests (LoadError)
```

for simplicity i replaced the name of my app with `<appname>`. I can see that the path below `<appame>` is duplicated spec/request/spec/requests

I don't know what I did (nothing?) to make this start automatically this wrong path.

When i test the models it's like this:

```
cannot load such file -- /Users/i814509/Dropbox/Ruby/Code/<appname>/spec/requests/spec/models (LoadError)
```

again automatically looking for the spec/requests directory before the one that I'm trying to specificy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified spec/requests but it seems to already be the default:
just run `bundle exec rspec`

Also, if you configured your environment, or don't use rvm/pik, you can just run `rspec`

Comment: okay that makes sense I can see here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/default-path that I can set a default path, but any ideas on how I can unset it?

Comment: I just set it like: rspec --default_path spec and now i have what i need. thanks for your help!